# quartz.properties location to be loaded automatically in JBoss AS 7.5

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I have managed to start quartz scheduler in JBoss As 7.5. But it reads default
properties file. I am not able to start Quartz using my user-defined quartz.properties. I have copy quartz.properties to src/main/resources. It did not work. I have copied to JBOSS_HOME/standalone\deployments. It did not work.
I have created custom module including quartz.properties. It did not work.
This is output

```
14:29:35,150 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.0 created.
14:29:35,151 INFO  [org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) RAMJobStore initialized.
14:29:35,153 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.0) '         DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

14:29:35,153 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (ServerService  Thread Pool -- 61) Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from   default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
14:29:35,153 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.0
```

I finally managed to get it working it by adding it as start up property to the application server (standalone.conf file) using this solution. http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/jboss-quartz/quartz-2-tutorial-on-jboss-as-7?showall=&start=1

Is this correct way?.  I think I need to copy it to a JBoss location to be recognized automatically. ALso above solution does not work in eclipse. I think MyEclipse starts Jboss in  different way( It does not use standalone.conf file). So I need to add Dorg.quartz.properties paramaters to Arguments in Run Configurations part.

PS: My deployment is in JAR format. It is not EAR/WAR.

Comment: are you using maven structure?

Comment: yes. I am using maven.

Comment: try placing them in resources directory?

Comment: I have already copy to src/main/resources in Maven structure

Comment: create a directory structure like org/quartz in the resources folder and try again, I have done this in one of my projects but I just can't recall the thing

Comment: did you also check in the same example that you have mentioned he is also using this while running the application: -Dorg.quartz.properties=/home/quartz/quartz.properties "

Comment: did you resolve it'? how?

Comment: No  I have not resolve. Specifying -Dorg.quartz.properties=/home/quartz/quartz.properties in standalone.conf file works as I said. But I am asking for best solution. Because when I work at development environment, Eclipse does not use standalone.conf file. So I have to specify again.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late, but I solved the problem of configuring Quartz in an Enterprise Application by placing the `quartz.properties`-file directly inside of the `src/main/resources`-directory of the specific `EJB`-submodule (using Quartz) of my `EAR`-project.